# How do I print status of task when using until with ansible?

Tags: loops, ansible

I googled myself to death for this. Let's assume I have the following Do-Until in ansible.

```
- shell: /usr/bin/foo
  register: result
  until: result == something
  retries: 200
  delay: 10
```

How can I print the `result` variable every 10 seconds (or every time this command executes) until this task finishes? Because now ansible is just printing one blank line every 10 seconds for this long running task. The user of my playbook could think something is awry when he only sees blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute playbook with `-vv` verbosity and see all the attempts.

Comment: In Ansible 2.4 that doesn't work as I'd expect. It simply displays a list of retries without the contents of a variable, e.g.: `FAILED - RETRYING: Check Ceph cluster health (60 retries left).`. I'd like to have the variable contents printed alongside that.

Comment: Preferably, I'd like to have that output printed without turning on verbose mode and only when iteration actually occurs. That would be perfect.

Comment: Make your own callback plugin that will do whatever you want it to.

Comment: So far I'm quite satisfied with using `stdout_callback = debug`, which produces a bit more informative results especially when looping over items.